# Virtual Host Apache2 doesn't work

Tags: apache, dns, webserver, virtualhost

I tried to add an second Domain to my dedicated server. My standard domain 1 should connect to normal /var/www/ path and my second domain should point to /var/www/domain.

Changed some thing (see comments) and now I get an 404 Error

My enabled sites configs look like:

default domain:

ServerAdmin mail@provider.com

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

second domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.second-domain.net
ServerAlias second-domain.net *.second-domain.net
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts Document:

```
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
2a06:1c40::xxx k4lim
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       domain1.name
185.101.92.XXX  domain2.name
```

T
he error I get when I try to open the site in Firefox is: The DNS Adress of the domain could not be found.

Would be really thankful for any ideas and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my problem:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.second-domain.net
ServerAlias second-domain.net *.second-domain.net
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

I forgot the /var/.... before /www/domain

Answer (score 1):

1. Does `nslookup domain2.name` show the right IP address?
2. Does `ping domain2.name` show the right IP address?
3. Is it a local or a world wide domain? If local you have to ask your local dns admin to add it.
4. Alternatively you can add it to `/etc/hosts` on your local machine. Not on the server.
5. Have a look at `cat /etc/resolv.conf` if the right dns server is listet.
6. If it's a global domain: Is there a connection to the outside?

Comment: 1. nslookup says
    Server:  UnKnown
    Address:  192.168.1.1

    No authorized answer: 
    Name:    domain2.name
    Address:  162.255.119.XXX (don't know this)

2. ping tells me the wrong IP
3. Its a world wide .net Domain
4. But that doesn't really help me on a world wide domain, does it?

Comment: If you change `/etc/hosts` you can redirect the domain to the right ip address. But that won't solve the real problem. Do you have another pc from which you can test the `nslookup domain2.name` command?

Comment: Are you sure that the domain is registered? You can use https://whois.icann.org/en to check it. That is the website of the international corporation for assigning domains.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that it is registered. Without the virtual host it works and points to my /var/www folder and shows the normale index.html. Do I have to change anything in my Domain DNS?

Comment: Well, if `nslookup` gets an error on the domain there has to be a dns error. Do you have a special dns configuration in your `/etc/resolve.conf`? If the domain has no global dns record you have to ask your domain provider to add it. Maybe you can change this by yourselfe via the homepage of your domain hoster.

Comment: My    resolve.conf is empty or doesn't exists? I got my domain on namecheap and can edit/configure quite much. My A-Record points to the IP, CNAME to the Domain and URL Redirect again to the Domain.

Comment: It's important that the CNAME entry doesn't point to the original domain. It's only used for subdomains. For example for local.domain2.name you can use the dns entries of mydomain.dynamicip.com. Which os do you use on your server and which os are you working with?

Comment: Does your webserver have a static ip address?

Comment: Furthermore you can change your `127.0.0.1 localhost 127.0.0.1 domain1.name` entry to `127.0.0.1 localhost domain1.name`. Just one line.

Comment: Yes, my webserver has an static IP Adress. Deleting the CNAME record resulted into getting an 404 error. My server is debian-7.0 and im currently working on Windows 10. Ping and nslookup still show the same.

Comment: Ok, on Windows you don't have a resolve.conf. The a-record contains the static ip of your webserver and the ip is reachable over the internet? I think you also don't need the redirect entry. the dns only combines the url your.domain with the ip address. i.e. domain.com -> 10.171.172.6

Comment: Also the resolv.conf on my server is empty (is that ok?). The only domain dns entry is left is the A record with the IP adress of the server.
I just realise that my    domain1 also points to the wrong(?) IP adress. 
If I ping both domains, they'll show the same domain, but not the domain of my server. If I open up the IP of my server my    domain1.name shows up.

Comment: Normaly your resolf.conf should contain at least two name servers `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` for exaple. These are the google dns servers. You can use them if your server can speak to the outside.

Comment: About the IP addresses: You have one Server with two public ipv4 addresses? Both can be reached from the internet?

Comment: Nope, it only has 1 ipv4 and a ipv6 adress. They can be reached from the Internet. I added the two nameservers to the     resolve.conf. Still 404.

Comment: Ok, and both Domains have the ipv4 address as destination? That means that a `nslookup domain.name` has to show your ip address. Otherwise there is something wrong in the config. If you just updated the ip adress today it could be that it takes one night until this takes effekt on the global dns servers. nslookup shows what ip is callen when you connect to your domain.

Comment: can you ask a frind with another internet connection to do a nslookup on your domain and tell you the output?

Comment: nslookup of a friend: 
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::1
Name:    domain.net
Yes both domains have the same ipv4 adress

Comment: Then the dns is noct up to date. I would recommend to wait until tomorrow and check again. If it hasn't changed you should ask yout domain host how to manage your ip adresses in the domain.